# Perl - How do I add up (calculate) numbers if they have same string in array

Tags: perl

I want to add up the following numbers if they have same string in array.

Example input:

```
AA 1  
AA 3  
AA 2  
BB 4  
BB 6
```

Desired output:

```
AA 6  
BB 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Hashes are useful for grouping.

```
my %sums;

while (<>) {
   my @F = split;
   $sums{$F[0]} += $F[1];
}

print("$_ $sums{$_}\n") for sort keys %sums;
```